# How to plot a line and column chart in react-highstock?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to plot a line chart and a column chart on separate y-axes in highstock using react. However, the line chart is hidden behind the column chart. Could I have the line chart on the column chart as shown in their example dual chart - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes?

[I've added a link to my chart to clarify my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBQip.png)

```
const chart_options= {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  tooltip:{
    split: false,
    shared:true,
    valueDecimals: 2
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    layout: 'horizontal' 
},
  series: [
    {
      name: 'ABC',
      type: 'line',
      data: this.props.data1,
      yAxis:1,
      color:'grey',
      lineWidth: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      type: 'line',
      data: this.props.data2,
      yAxis:0,
    },
    {
      name: 'GHI',
      type: 'column',
      data: this.props.data3,
      yAxis:0,
      color: '#ffd699',
      dataGrouping:{
        enabled: false
    },
    pointWidth: 1
    },
  ],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    gridLineWidth:1,
    title: {
      text: 'Time'
    },
    tickPixelInterval: 5
  },
  yAxis:  [
    {
    labels: {
      format: '{value:.0f}%',
    },
    opposite: false,
    tickPixelInterval: 20
  },
  {
    title: {
    labels: {
      format: '{value:.2f}',
    },
    tickPixelInterval: 20
  },
],
}
```

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Turns out the problem was in the order of the series list. I changed the order to what I would like plotted first second and third and the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `zIndex` propert for the series:

```
series: [{
  zIndex: 1,
  ...
}, {
  zIndex: 0,
  ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x5aefpLv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.zIndex